# Trouble implementing ArrayList Iterator in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Here's my implementation of an `iterator`over an `ArrayList`:

```
public class MyClass {

    List<E> list = new ArraList<E>();

public Iterator<E> iterator() {

        return new MyIterator<E>();
    }

private class MyIterator<T> implements Iterator<E> {

     int index;

        public MyIterator() {

            index = 0;

        }

        public E next() {

            if (hasNext()){
            index++;
            return list.get(index + 1);
        }

        else
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {

        if ((list.get(index + 1) != null) && (index < list.size() -1)){
                index++;
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }

        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

    }

}
```

However, although the logic looks alright to me, this implementation is wrong, because it does not work properly.

My question is: what am i doing wrong, and how can i change it in order for it to work properly?

UPDATE:

```
public E next() {

        if (index == 0) {
            index++;
            return list.get(0);
        }

        else if (hasNext()) {
            index++;
            return list.get(index);
        }

        else
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
```

I've managed to, somehow, make it work, but now the next method is skipping indexes of the array. How can i fix this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "work properly"? You might find it easier to figure out what's going on if you write a unit test for your code.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work properly" - be specific. Also, what exactly is a `PacoteIterator`

Comment: @Trisha the next method returns an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`i don't know why

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll sorry i've edited it! translation issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an example of how you're using this iterator, it's hard to give you advice. That being said, here's at least two things you are doing incorrect. In your `next()` method, you have

```
index++;
return list.get(index + 1);
```

So you will first be incrementing the index, and then returning the NEXT index. This should result in an out of bounds exception. Change it to return `list.get(index);`

Secondly, your `hasNext()` method isn't ordered correctly. That is, you should check whether your next index is valid before checking whether the next object exists or not. Re-order your if statement to:

```
if ((index < list.size() -1) && (list.get(index + 1) != null))
```

Also get rid of the `index++;` line in `hasNext()`. The method should just be checking for validity, not actually changing your current index. That should happen in `next()`.

Comment: i'm using the iterator to navigate through the list, getting a specific element, print a specific element, that kind of operations. my issue is with the `next()` and `hasNext()` methods that are not doing what they're supposed to do

Comment: Well in that case, check my edit. I think I found 2 more things you've done incorrectly.

Comment: You should do a println to see exactly which indices are being skipped. As is, I believe the `next()` method is correct, so your new problem is probably in the `hasNext()` method.